# is there an r code that can select based on 3 columns and returns a value based on the options

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I want to create a new variable name based on roof, wall and floor. if any of the options has 1 then the new variable is assigned 1 and zero otherwise.

```
roof<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
    wall<-c(0,1,1,0,0,0)
    floor<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
    data<-data.frame(roof,wall,floor)
    data
    data$code<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pmap`:

```
library(tidyverse)

roof<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
wall<-c(0,1,1,0,0,0)
floor<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
data<-data.frame(roof,wall,floor)

#
data %>%
  mutate(code_want = pmap_int(data %>%
                                select(roof:floor) %>%
                                mutate_all(as.logical), any))

#   roof wall floor code code_want
#1    1    0     1    1         1
#2    1    1     1    1         1
#3    1    1     1    1         1
#4    0    0     0    0         0
#5    1    0     1    1         1
#6    0    0     0    0         0
```